# Find MAX LEN name against duplicate IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Being a beginner at SQL, I'm stuck.

I have a table structure like thi:

```
+------+-------+-----------------------------------------+
| id   | name     | content                              |
+------+-------+-----------------------------------------+
| 1    | Jack     | ...                                  |
| 2    | Dan      | ...                                  |
| 1    | Joe      | ...                                  |
| 1    | Jeoffery | ...                                  |
+------+-------+-----------------------------------------+
```

What I want to do is that I want to select the Distinct IDs along with the name with max length against that specific id.

For e.g: Against ID 1, it should return Jeoffery while against ID 2, Dan.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Abis! Please show the SQL statement(s) you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT id, 
           name, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LEN(name) DESC)
)
SELECT id,
       name
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Can you please explain `;WITH CTE` and `RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LEN(name) DESC)` part. Explanation would help me in future too.

Comment: @AbisSyed a CTE is a [common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx), and here is a link for [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)